# How to "log in" to a website using access_token

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to post a request to log in to a website using the `Requests` module.

```
import requests


session = requests.Session()

url = '...'
payload = '{"email":"my_email@gmail.com","password":"12345678*"}'
HEADER = {"content-type": "application/json"}
r = session.post(url=url, data=payload, headers=HEADER)
```

`<Response [200]>`

```
{
  "data": {
    "access_token": "T6u_VkzP9PkeRTHbPGVmH8gjGUcz8y_XwSMhc",
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJI"
  },
  "message": "OK"
}
```

Now I try to get the page and see if I can see the element that exists if my user logged in (for example my name..):

```
token = json.loads(r.text)['data']['access_token']
h = {'Authorization': token}
personal_page_url = '....'
r = session.get(url=personal_page_url, headers=h) or r = session.get(url=personal_page_url, data=h)
```

And all i can see the this `Captcha` page and not my personal page.

Any suggestions how to use this token ?

**EDIT**

This is all the information form `Network` tab in my `chrome`:

```
General

Request URL: https://www.yad2.co.il/personal/posts
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 141.226.253.90:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers

Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sat, 22 Oct 2022 18:52:31 GMT
Set-Cookie: __uzmc=9226236134145; HttpOnly; path=/; Expires=Sat, 22-Apr-23 18:52:31 GMT ; Max-Age=15724800; SameSite=Lax
Set-Cookie: __uzmd=1666464751; HttpOnly; path=/; Expires=Sat, 22-Apr-23 18:52:31 GMT ; Max-Age=15724800; SameSite=Lax
Set-Cookie: __uzmf=7f60001a351c8f-eaff-4593-8f28-1608d1067d2316653901902961074560738-07340a3d3abf80aa361; HttpOnly; path=/; Expires=Sat, 22-Apr-23 18:52:31 GMT ; Max-Age=15724800; SameSite=Lax
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Via: 1.1 a54cda8ccda3480314f451558e4dd062.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: AOruLPHS3MNR0VAhyXx5WXqxt0K90H16MJbJONDVqzsoxmxfzubjDQ==
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: FRA60-P3
x-amz-version-id: null
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN;
X-Xss-Protection: 1;

Request Headers

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: __uzma=9b00ee88-fdcb-4618-a086-926fe1d0e135; __uzmb=1665390190; __uzme=9550; abTestKey=92; y2018-2-cohort=10; leadSaleRentFree=60; use_elastic_search=1; bc.visitor_token=6985233079423275008; y2session=gfiod758btt6mq0t87mfr1rdj7; recommendations-searched-1=21; recommendations-searched-3=0; recommendations-home-category={"categoryId":3,"subCategoryId":0}; y2_cohort_2020=58; canary=never; server_env=production; personalRedirect=1; favorites_userid=fvu4934081; refresh_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJFbWFpbCI6ImZhbHVra3lAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiVXNlcklEIjo0OTM0MDgxLCJGaXJzdE5hbWUiOiLXqNeR15nXkSIsIkxhc3ROYW1lIjoi16nXmNeZ15nXoNeR16jXkiIsImlzQ2FyVHJhZGVyIjowLCJpc0NhckFjY2Vzc29yeVRyYWRlciI6MCwiaXNUb3VyaXNtVHJhZGVyIjowLCJpc1JlYWxFc3RhdGVNYXJrZXRpbmciOjAsIllhZDJUcmFkZSI6MCwiRW1haWxWZXJpZmllZCI6IjIwMjEtMTEtMjdUMTc6MDY6NDIuMDAwWiIsImlzVHdvV2hlZWxlZFRyYWRlciI6MCwiVGl2IjowLCJpYXQiOjE2NjY0MTgzNDksImV4cCI6MTY3NDE5NDM0OX0.TZi9X0ippZoIJnGP1afdsNAEMwo_ktBEyCQh0jcGD58; __uzmc=3827935822160; __uzmd=1666447956; __uzmf=7f60001a351c8f-eaff-4593-8f28-1608d1067d2316653901902961057766489-7ce2e5538791c6fc358; access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJFbWFpbCI6ImZhbHVra3lAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiVXNlcklEIjo0OTM0MDgxLCJGaXJzdE5hbWUiOiLXqNeR15nXkSIsIkxhc3ROYW1lIjoi16nXmNeZ15nXoNeR16jXkiIsImlzQ2FyVHJhZGVyIjowLCJpc0NhckFjY2Vzc29yeVRyYWRlciI6MCwiaXNUb3VyaXNtVHJhZGVyIjowLCJpc1JlYWxFc3RhdGVNYXJrZXRpbmciOjAsIllhZDJUcmFkZSI6MCwiRW1haWxWZXJpZmllZCI6IjIwMjEtMTEtMjdUMTc6MDY6NDIuMDAwWiIsImlzVHdvV2hlZWxlZFRyYWRlciI6MCwiVGl2IjowLCJpYXQiOjE2NjY0NjQ3MTUsImV4cCI6MTY2NjQ2NTYxNX0.W6AEWOKLSPiSbzxKVfTtnQYkkOUIIP-EVAFEwFYBVCs
Host: www.yad2.co.il
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-GPC: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: `h = {'Authorization': token}` Check to make sure this is the correct format for the `Authorization header` and not `token {token}` or `bearer {token}` or something like that.  Also, be aware that websites *can* block non browser based access fairly effectively so you might be getting a captcha because they don't want scripts to hit their site

Answer (score 0):

First: to POST JSON data to a server using `requests`, use `json=` parameter:

```py
# ...

payload = {"email": "my_email@gmail.com", "password": "12345678*"} # <-- use dict here
r = session.post(url=url, json=payload)  # <-- use json= parameter

#...
```

---

If the response from the server is:

```py
# data = r.json()
# then data is:
data = {
    "data": {
        "access_token": "T6u_VkzP9PkeRTHbPGVmH8gjGUcz8y_XwSMhc",
        "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJI",
    },
    "message": "OK",
}

# you can try (but specifics depend on API, could be Bearer <token> or Token <token>

h = {"Authorization": "bearer {}".format(data["data"]["access_token"])}
r = session.get(url=personal_page_url, headers=h)
```

---

EDIT: To use cookies:

```py
payload = {
    "email": "my_email@gmail.com",
    "password": "12345678*",
}  # <-- use dict here
r = session.post(url=url, json=payload)  # <-- use json= parameter

data = r.json()

session.cookies["access_token"] = data["data"]["access_token"]
session.cookies["refresh_token"] = data["data"]["refresh_token"]

r = session.get(url=personal_page_url)
```

Comment: Still received Captcha

Comment: I did not understand about the Bearer & Token you mentioned, I only try {"Authorization": "bearer {}".format(data["data"]["access_token"])}, Can I try another approach ?

Comment: @user979033 I recommend to look at the documentation about the API and how the token should be used. Could be `{"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(data["data"]["access_token"])}` or something else. It's hard to guess...

Comment: It has no record.
This is a site for second hand sale and only on this page can I see my ad id with which I can do an AP PUT and jump the ad.

Comment: I already take a look, Please see my edit

Comment: What comes after session.cookies['access_token'] = ? can I have simple code example ?

Comment: BTW the token looks different probably because I logged in after I post my post

Comment: Unfortunately same results...

Comment: @user979033 Try to set different headers, for example `User-Agent`. Some sites check it and if isn't standard browser then block it. But that I leave to you to experiment with.